# Google Maps Javascript API showing map in small square

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented the Google maps JavaScript API and I am trying to get a full screen map.

The map itself is only showing in a small box in the corner, I know the container is the right size as I have google elements on each corner but the map isn't filling the container.

Here's what I have:
[image: Screenshot Of Map]

The code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAh_6k9o89NOW69iR9mL_0J6vu9QMm_54w&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script> 
<script> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

var map;

function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508800670335646,-0.06943131238223),
        zoom: 12,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        draggable : true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [
    {
        featureType: 'water',
        stylers: [{color:'#46bcec'},{visibility:'on'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'landscape',
        stylers: [{color:'#f2f2f2'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'road',
        stylers: [{saturation: -100},{lightness: 45}]
    },{
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'simplified'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'road.arterial',
        elementType: 'labels.icon',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'administrative',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{color: '#444444'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'transit',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    },{
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    }
],

    }

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var locations = [

    ];

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: '',
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
    }
}
</script> 

<style> 
#map{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
```

Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that all the code you have or is this in the <head> section of a larger webpage? When I copied your code into a skeleton HTML structure, the map is fullscreen.

Comment: @BlakeSimpson this is just the head section of the site

Comment: you can tell it's the right size because of the controls so only one map tile is showing. I've had this problem before, either caused by some error or when trying to show/hide the map canvas, just incase you have *any* errors or you are playing with the visibility of the map.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=fr#HTML5

Comment: I have also seen this issue before when the map element is initially hidden when the google map script loads and the element is then shown later. Then you must call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

Comment: Thanks for your input on this - yes the map element is initially hidden, where would I call that function? sorry a bit new to all this.

Comment: It depends how you make the map visible, can you provide this code? If it is a jQuery event, after the "show()", run the google resize event.

Comment: Thanks for all your input, it is now working perfectly, working code here jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/SD9km/1 for anyones reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

`html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }`

in your stylesheet/css

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/SD9km/1/

Comment: Yeah, this is already there, the container itself is the right size, its the map itself thats not...

Comment: share the complete HTML including the container.Do you have inline css in the #map?

Comment: Thanks for your input - full code here http://jsfiddle.net/SD9km/

Comment: updated your code, it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/SD9km/1/

Comment: You need to call the init on document.ready

Answer (score 2):

Your map container is becoming 100% the width and height of nothing.

Try this....

```
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```